# Write mysql custom query in query builder of grafana

Tags: grafana

I made a time-series graph screenshot attached and the generated query is

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_of_sign_up) DIV 600 * 600 AS "time",
  status AS "borrower_status",
  count(id) AS "Number Of Borrowers"
FROM borrowers
WHERE
  date_of_sign_up BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1631158800) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1643881661) AND
  status IN ('APPROVED','INACTIVE','BASIC') AND
  client_id = 130454654
GROUP BY 1, status
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_of_sign_up) DIV 600 * 600
```

Now i want to pass from and to from url in mysql query builder, below is the query i tried to write but it did not work

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(date_of_sign_up,10m),
  status AS "borrower_status",
  count(id) AS "Number Of Borrowers"
FROM borrowers
WHERE
 date_of_signup between $from AND $to  AND
  status IN (${BorrowerStatus}) AND
  client_id = [[tenant]]
GROUP BY 1, status
ORDER BY $__timeGroup(date_of_sign_up,10m)
```

What is the correct way of passing **&from and &to from URL params in MySQL query builder date_of_signup between**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date_of_signup between $__timeFrom() AND $__timeTo()
```